# Can't get the fibonacci, returning 0

Tags: python

```
def fib_memo(n, memo={}):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 0
    try:
        return memo[n]
    except KeyError:
        result = fib_memo(n-1, memo) + fib_memo(n-2, memo)
        memo[n] = result
        return result

for i in range(121):
    print('fib', str(i),fib_memo(i))
```

Returning the following output

```
fib 0 0
fib 1 0
fib 2 0
fib 3 0
fib 4 0
fib 5 0
fib 6 0
fib 7 0
fib 8 0
fib 9 0
fib 10 0
```

Comment: `return n` and not `return 0`, because summing 0 always gives 0

Answer (score 2):

`fib(1)` is 1, not 0, so you need to change `if n==0 or n==1: return 0` to `if n==0 or n==1: return n`.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't so keen on my mistakes. appreciate